# NSArray and tableview cocoa app

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have an `NSArray` with instances of an object with several attributes. I want to know how to display the `NSString` and int attributes of the instances in a tableview in a cocoa application. Sorry I am new to this.

card is designed to hold attributes of the individual cards.

`deck` is designed to hold an `NSArray` filled with cards and a name in order to be referenced by `deckBuilder` and `deckConstruction`.

`deckBuilder` is used to build instances of decks based on it's attribute, `newDeck`. (`newDeck` starts with all possible cards, and is copied with card entries removed to create new decks)

`deckConstruction` is the user interface, the .xib contains a table that is supposed to display the names of cards in the `NSMutableArray`, decks and  the number values in the `NSMutableArray`, numberOf.

I cannot find a source on how to go about filling this table from the array though. (code supplied consists of 4 .h files for these objects)

```
//This is the Card object
//  Card.h
//  ProjectJJ
//
//  Created by Guest User on 3/23/14.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject
{
    //defining what makes up a card
    NSString *name;
    NSString *attribute;
    float level;
    NSString *type;
    NSString *info;
    float attack;
    float defence;
    float cardNum;
}

@property (readwrite) NSString *name;
@property (readwrite) NSString *attribute;
@property (readwrite) float level;
@property (readwrite) NSString *type;
@property (readwrite) NSString *info;
@property (readwrite) float attack;
@property (readwrite) float defence;
@property (readwrite) float cardNum;
- (void)cards;

@end


// this is the deck object
//  deck.h
//  Cardsim
//
//  Created by Guest User on 4/11/14.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Card.h"
//the deck object for the users decks
@interface deck : NSObject
{
    NSString *deckName; // the deck name
    NSMutableArray *allCards;//will display in the interface all the cards in the database so the user can pick and choose from these
    NSArray *numCardsInDeck;//will be next allCards indicating the number of each of the cards in the database that the user has put into their deck
    NSMutableArray *cardsInDeck;//the acutal cards in thier deck
}

@property (readwrite) NSString *deckName;
@property (readwrite) NSArray *allCards;
@property (readwrite) Card *impendingFortress;
@property (readwrite) Card *fortressSoldier;
@property (readwrite) Card *fortressKnight;
@property (readwrite) Card *fortressArcher;
@property (readwrite) Card *fortressMage;
@property (readwrite) Card *appocalypticBeast;

- (void)setDeckCards:(NSArray *)c;

@end

// this is the NSWindowController
//  deckConstruction.h
//  Cardsim
//
//  Created by Guest User on 4/2/14.
//
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "deckBuilder.h"
#import "deck.h"


@interface deckConstruction : NSWindowController
{
    NSMutableArray *decks;
    NSMutableArray *numberOf;
    deckBuilder *deckMaker;
}

@property (readwrite) NSString *deckName;

- (void)setDecks:(NSMutableArray *)a;

@end

//
//  deckBuilder.h
//  Cardsim
//
//  Created by Guest User on 4/18/14.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "deck.h"
#import "card.h"

@interface deckBuilder : NSObject
{
    deck *newDeck;
    NSArray *numCard;
}

- (deck *)conDeck;

@end
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: `readwrite` attribute is set as default, you should omit this one.

Comment: Also you should remove ivars in `@interface ... { //ivars here }` because Xcode automatically create ivars and synthesise properties. You can access directly to ivars like this: `_name`, `_attribute`, `_level`, etc. underscore `_` instead of `self.`.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new and only use Objective-c right now.

The new TableView in Cocoa is table contain nsview in every single cell. To add value to each single cell. you will need to add the dependencry to the class where it manage the view.

```
AppDelegate:< NSTableViewDataSource, NSTabViewDelegate>
```

Remember to link the table to this class.
You need to let talbe know how many row it has

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return <number of row in the data>;
}
```

In the implementation, you call

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
                  row:(NSInteger)row 
{
    NSTextField *result = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:[<your tableview> frame]];
    // Add your custom for the cell in here.
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

This will Function called and go throught every cell in your table.
Hope this help.